# Can I start a sentence with the word maybe?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, usage

Can I use the word maybe to start this sentence?

> "Maybe this week won't be so bad after all."

Comment: "Maybe" is an adverb which means "perhaps", "possibly", which you surely can start a sentence with. So, there is nothing wrong in starting with "maybe" either.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with that sentence, and no problem starting a sentence with maybe.